# Launch Images for Dark or Light Mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, ios-darkmode

How can I choose a different set of Launch images for Dark mode and for Light mode?

I have a LaunchImages set. When the application starts, an image is shown. For Light mode it seems good, however if I try to open my application on a device set to Dark mode (iOS 13), this image seems bad.

During the start application I can not use any code for dynamic changes and I have no options in XCode interface for managing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the Launch Screen loads before the app starts executing, it would not be possible to change the launch images set programmatically.

However, in the *Image Set* tab, you can change the *Appearance* option to enable a different set of images for Light and Dark modes:

[image]

So, if you set this image in the Launch Screen Storyboard, the result would be as below:

[image]

On a side note, if the need is just to change the background color, not the images, you may set the Launch Screen Storyboard view background color to *System Background Color* and just use transparent PNG images.

Comment: What is different between any, dark and any, light ,dark?

Comment: "Any, dark" lets you specify two appearance variations (one for light / any ie older versions). "Any, light, dark" lets you specify three, which you might want if you wanted to vary the appearance between devices that don't support light/dark mode and light mode on devices that do support it.

Comment: "System Background Color" does not work for me... Background always stays white.

Answer (score 4):

1. Xcode 11 supports only storyboard Launch screen files. It means I
   should use storyboards.
2. In storyboards we can use UIImageViews + images from .xcassets.
   Assets support images with different variants: Light, Dark modes. You can apply constraints for positioning them on screen.
3. If you support iOS before 11.0 you can not use system dynamic colors for backgrounds of the screen view. In this case you put additional dynamic image to screen as background and apply leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints with negative values. Negative values are needed for covering Top and Bottom Bars. (I used -64px)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add dark appearance for your asset, or for the asset color you are using, like in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this to use light and dark mode images

1. Step 1 - Create image set in assets.xassets like this
   [image]
2. Step 2 - Select Image select like this

[image]

3. Steps 3 - Change appearance to Any, Light , Dark like this
   [image]

[image]

4. Add your images for any light and dark mode like this and use this image wherever you need it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for my experience, sometimes Launch image is changed when you erase your app, turn off your device and turn on again.

Comment: yep I was about to pull my hair out - why does it not work on my device. works after a reboot of device, just re-installing app wasn't enough..