# How to customize theme for Flutter iOS LaunchScreen.storyboard for Light and Dark

Tags: ios, flutter, storyboard, themes

I'm building a `Flutter` app and I wanted to make the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` changes its appearance based on the `iOS` theme mode, so when the OS is in `Light` mode and the user starts the app, the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` should have a light background color at launch time and when in `Dark` mode it should have a dark background color.

Is it possible to implement such behavior?

Comment: With  [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package you can implement such a behaviour.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yes, I checked it out but I need more control over the LanuchStoryboard file, than this package offers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch Images for Dark or Light Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288101/launch-images-for-dark-or-light-mode)

Comment: @user18309290 They explained the images and not the background mechanism, so kinda no not what I'm looking for!

Comment: The same principle works for Color Set too.

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892053/dark-mode-launch-screen-in-ios-13